# How to avoid the automatic scrolling of a textview to start over when a handler is postdelayed?

Tags: java, android, textview, autoscroll

I have a textview with text auto scrolling horizontally when it is too long. I also have a seekbar updated every second with an handler.postdelayed.
Everytime the handler is postdelayed it started the scrolling of the textview from the beginning. How can I avoid that ?

Here is the textview XML code :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/play"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Titre"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I also set it selected in the Oncreate() method:

```
    findViewById(R.id.titre).setSelected(true);
```

And here is the code to update the seekbar :

```
            seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 0);
```

With :

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        seek_bar.setProgress((int) (mPlayer.getPlaybackState().positionMs / 1000));
        textviewEcoule.setText(MinSec((int) (mPlayer.getPlaybackState().positionMs / 1000)));
        int reste = seek_bar.getMax() - (int) (mPlayer.getPlaybackState().positionMs / 1000);
        textviewRestant.setText(MinSec(reste));
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }
};
```

Every second the scrolling of the textview starts over. how can I avoid this ?